# Clever Programmer Javascript tutorial Age in Days Challenge

Tags: javascript, typeerror, appendchild

For the age in Days challenge in this video, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') at yearBorn (script.js:10:47) at        HTMLButtonElement.onclick (challenge.html:19:64) yearBorn @ script.js:10 onclick @ challenge.html:19
```

JS:

function yearBorn() {

```
var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born?');
var ageInDays = (2022 - birthYear) \* 365;
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');    
var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDays + ' days old');
h1.setAttribute('id', 'yearBorn');
h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
```

html:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <title>Javascript Challenge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/index.css"
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-1">
      <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
      <div class="flex-box-container-1">
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="yearBorn()">Click Me</button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-box-container-1">
        <div class="flex-box-result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting the error?

I was expecting the age in days to print to the flex box container below the buttons in the document.  Instead, getting the error

Comment: Is that `\*` a typo?

Comment: You have `flex-box-result` as a class not an id. I don't know anything about how Bootstrap works though.

Comment: "in this video"...which video? This question is the first result in search engines when I search for your title, or parts of it. I'm not going to sign up on a website just to understand your question - can you either explain the object of the challenge or remove the reference to that and make the question just about the error you're getting?

Comment: It references Clever Programmer JavaScript crash course video available on YouTube.  The object of the challenge is to create a button that calculates the approximate age in days of the user based on their birth year.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1
The error in this line

```
document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1)
```

Because document.getElementById() need an id which you provide when creating html element like this

```
<div id="id"></div>
```

Your flex-box-result is a class

```
<div class="flex-box-result"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="flex-box-result"></div>
```

Solution 2
In JavaScript code, you can also use a querySelector method with the selector of your element (like CSS selector)

```
document.querySelector('.flex-box-result').appendChild(h1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Changed  flex box result from class to id and it ran.  Thanks!

Comment: @dynermite don't forget to upvote and accept answers if they resolve your question

Comment: upvote me if thats help yout